# List of generic class

Tags: java, list, generics, arraylist

I have `Example1`  and `Example2` classes. I added just one field in each class:

```
public class Example1 {
   private String test1;
   //setter and getter
}

public class Example2 {
   private String test2;
   //setter and getter
}
```

Now I need to pass a list from one of these two classes to a method. In fact I want to have a method that can accept a list from both of these classes as parameter. I know Generic classes, but I don't know how can I use generic classes in this case. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:
For example suppose I have two methods like this:

```
public void workingMethod1(List<Example1> list){
}
public void workingMethod2(List<Example2> list){
}
```

In fact, I want to combine these two methods and have one method.

Comment: You need both classes to inherit from the same `class`. Or use a `List<? extends Object>`, in which case the items in the `List` will be treated as `Object`.

Comment: I think the second way is better. I will try it. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I agree with hamed use List<? extends Object>

Comment: Why would `List<? extends Object>` be better? From the sounds of things, these two classes are related (you can use one instead of the other in your function), and so they presumably share some functionality - why not represent this in the class hierarchy?

Comment: Alternatively, you could just overload the method...

Comment: @will, if the classes are indeed related, then maybe inheritance is likely a better option or even a single class with an overloaded method but the OP has begun the discussion about generics, hence why we went down the discussion about generics.

Comment: @BoristheSpider `Or use a List<? extends Object>` ... right, who cares about type safety.

Comment: @JamieReid A discussion about generics is ok, but suggesting `List<? extends Object>` is definitely wrong in this context, because OP expects very specific types in the passed list.

Comment: @Tom. ok point taken. To be quite honest, it's not entirely clear why the OP needs two classes.
I guess we need OP back in the discussion giving us more info.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimers:

1. I've been drinking, and so this may be riddled with typos.
2. I haven't done much java rcently, and don't have it on my current machine
3. I haven't kept up to date with changes since 1.6, so may miss some modern techniques.

There are two ways i would look at doing this. One would be by having a common class of the two classes you're looking at, and the other would be to overload the method you want to be able to deal with both possible lists.

I also don't understand why generics are needed here.

approach 1:

```
public class BaseClass{
   // whatever
}

public class Example1 extends BaseClass{
   // whatever
}

public class Example2 extends BaseClass {
   // whatever
}


public void workingMethod(List<BaseClass> list){
   // whatever
}
```

Or, the other route, if the two classes don't have much in common, would be to just overload the `workingMethod` method:

```
public class Example1{
   // whatever
}

public class Example2{
   // whatever
}

public void workingMethod(List<Example1> list){
  // do whatever to create the list needed to call the function you want
  List<Double> someCrap = new List<Double>();
  for(Example1 e1 : list){
    someCrap.add(e1.getRandomCrap());
  }
  commonWorkingMethod(someCrap );
}

public void workingMethod(List<Example2> list){
  // do whatever to create the list needed to call the function you want
  List<Double> etc = new List<Double>();
  // do more crap
  commonWorkingMethod(etc);
}

public void commonWorkingMethod(List<Double> list){
   // whatever
}
```

Comment: Your second approach won't compile, because both `workingMethod` implementations have the same erasure. Btw: `I also don't understand why generics are needed here.` Well, you're still using them, so they are somehow needed :P.

Comment: Huh. I did not know this. And i thought generics was specifically using something like `<? extends BaseClass>`, not just using class hierarchy.

Comment: This is just a kind of generic (`?` is a wildcard). So everything between `<` and `>` is "generic" :D.

Answer (score -2):

I have created a really basic code sample based on Boris the Spider's suggestion above. It is just skeleton code and has no functionality. It just shows the idea of the generic in the method and the two classes.

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Test {
    public class Example1 {
    }

    public class Example2 {
    }

    public static void workingMethod1(List<? extends Object> list){

    }
    public static void workingMethod2(List<? extends Object> list){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        Test t = new Test();
        Example1 eg1 = t.new Example1();
        Example2 eg2 = t.new Example2();
        List<Example1> list1 = new ArrayList<Example1>();
        List<Example1> list2 = new ArrayList<Example1>();

        workingMethod1(list1);
        workingMethod2(list2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. And since both methods also accept `List<File>`, `List<String>`, `List<Date>`, ... you don't have to care about type safety.

Comment: If the OP is knowledgeable enough type safety can be handled in the code, this is just skeleton code. Just because you can send any object into a method doesn't mean the method has to accept it or cause any real problems.

Comment: I'm on @tom s side here, and I don't know of its any kind of recommended standard, imo it's better to ha e the function signature descrobe(at least somehwat) how the function should be used, rather than trying it and seeing what errors you get later.

Comment: @will You can avoid exceptions if you check each entry like `entry instanceof DesiredType`, but the purpose of using generics is to avoid checks like this. And yes, a signature that includes the generic is more verbose and helpful.

Comment: @Tom I really haven't been keeping up to date with the changes to java (since 1.6), but how does checking if it's an instance prevent exceptions? surely you either check the typ inside the function, and throw if it's the wrong type (which you'd catch outside), or you just check the type before calling and send program flow to the same place anyway.

Comment: @will Well, what kind of exception do you expect if you successfully checked the type of an entry? And if the type doesn't match, then you might just ignore that entry, instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @Tom, pèrsonally, I would ignore rather than throw. No need to throw an exception as that would cause it's own problems as you say,